# How start animation on focus?

Tags: android

I want to start an animation like a fade whenever a Text-view or Image-view is in focus (viewing it_pressing at it like holding) without clicking.
If you have an idea how to find a solution.

Comment: what you mean by focus? like when you look at the view?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: What is holing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [OnFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) and start your animation when a view will on focus